# Circle bullets for background with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, background, repeat, codepen

The code in CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/aleprieto/pen/nAmIy#code-area) provides bullets, stripes and some squares. I want circles. I found [this source](https://davidwalsh.name/css-circles) but I don't know how to implement it.

*Code also here*

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
div {
text-align: center;
font: bold 21px 'Oswald',sans-serif;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff, 2px 2px 0 #999;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dotted {
padding: 2.25em 1.6875em;
background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(45px 45px, circle cover, rgba(0,0,0,.90), rgba(0,0,0,.90) 2px, transparent 0px, transparent 100%);
background-image: -moz-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
background-image: -ms-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
-webkit-background-size: 9px 9px;
-moz-background-size: 9px 9px;
background-size: 9px 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by changing the radius, notice the `rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 4px` instead of `rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 1px` on the first line about `background-image:`.

[image]

*Code*

```
.dotted {
  padding: 2.25em 1.6875em;
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 4px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: -moz-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: -ms-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  -webkit-background-size: 3px 3px;
  -moz-background-size: 3px 3px;
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks You ! It woks !

Comment: Nice, do not hesitate to ask further question and close this one by accepting.